# Merge two hooks for the same mode into one

Tags: emacs, elisp

How can I merge this two lines into just one hook?

```
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'(lambda () (yas-activate-extra-mode 'html-mode)))
  (add-hook 'web-mode-hook #'(lambda () (yas-activate-extra-mode 'css-mode))))
```

Everything I've tried so far didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`mapcar` is, I believe, what you want:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda ()
                           (mapcar #'yas-activate-extra-mode
                                   '(html-mode css-mode))))
```

(I'm using an old version of yasnippet so haven't been able to test this.)

Comment: **or**:  `(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda () (yas-activate-extra-mode 'html-mode) (yas-activate-extra-mode 'css-mode) ))`

Comment: Agreed: that's pretty straightforward (and probably more new-user-friendly).

Comment: You should also use `mapc` in this scenario and not `mapcar`. `mapc` works the same except it doesn't collect all the results into a list you don't use. Also it is better form to use named functions for hooks, not lambdas. That way you can removed them easily by name if needed. like `(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (defun my-web-mode-setup-hook () ...))`, or better yet, define the function elsewhere and just pass in the quoted name so you can redefine the hook more easily without needed to remove it or eval something deeply nested in config code.

Comment: Agreed on the named function point; the answer was simply an attempt to modify OP's code as minimally as possible.  And agreed that `mapc` would be fine since it's all for side effects.

Comment: lawlist, would you mind to write your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct? :-D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```lisp
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (yas-activate-extra-mode 'html-mode)
  (yas-activate-extra-mode 'css-mode) ))
```